# Why does jQuery's :visible selector work differently when filtered?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I noticed today that jQuery's `:visible` selector shows an unexpected behaviour when combined with an attribute selector. Its behaviour differs depending on
a) whether it is used inline or within the filter method
b) the type of attribute selector it's combined with

Examples:

*Given the following markup*

```
<input required name="name" type="text" />
```

*The following is true for jQuery*

```
$('[required="required"]').filter(':visible').length == 0; //true
$('[required="required"]:visible').length == 0; //false - why does jquery find the input?
```

The `disabled` attribute shows similar behaviour. However, data attributes do not show the same behaviour:

*Given the following markup*

```
<input data-boolean name="name" type="text" />
```

*The following is true for jQuery*

```
$('[data-boolean="true"]').filter(':visible').length == 0; //true
$('[data-boolean="true"]:visible').length == 0; //true
```

Here's a link to a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dxncxj4p/) that demonstrates the problem.

I wouldn't expect [required="required"] to match an element with a blank required attribute, and it doesn't when used as a selector on its own, but it does when paired with the :visible selector. **Why is this?**

Comment: Attributes like `required` do get a value, that being the attribute name itself, and that's whether your markup includes the value or not. The `data-boolean` example is different, because there's no implied value for such attributes.

Comment: $('[required]', '#myForm3').filter(':visible') seems to be working correctly as well as  $('[required]:visible', '#myForm3')

Comment: The difference is almost certainly caused by a disagreement between the native `querySelectorAll()` code and what Sizzle does. The native code will be used when there's no `:visible` selector, but Sizzle is used when it's there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The root cause of the difference seems to be that Sizzle (the non-native selector code in jQuery) matches boolean attributes like `required` when an explicit test is made for the formal default attribute value. The native `querySelectorAll()` code, however, does not, unless the attribute actually had the value in the original HTML.

Boolean selectors like `required` or `readonly` can be expressed in HTML without a value, but that implies that the value is to be taken as the attribute name itself.

When you use a pseudo-class like `:visible`, then Sizzle realizes that the native code won't work so it takes over. It's not the `:visible` test itself that causes the problem; you get the same effect with `:text` or any other extension supported by Sizzle (and which doesn't change the sense of the selector, obviously).

Personally I would consider this a bug, though it may be somewhat difficult to fix because the attribute value really is reported as being `required` when the DOM node is interrogated via `getAttribute()`.

If HTML code were to be meticulously written with the attributes fully specified:

```
<input required=required ...>
```

then there'd be no perceived difference, but that seems a little burdensome.